# Selenium IDE open command

Tags: selenium-ide

I am creating automation tests using selenium IDE.

I want to navigate to an url using the open command, And then click on a button on the page , so that I can edit the Record.

After Navigating to the url(hashed url) using the open command.
The Execution stops at this command.

The base url is http://test.com/ and 
the url to navigate is http://test.com/#quotes/1

Comment: there are old threads which says the # (jail) character could be a problem in selenium. We had tests on a page with # without any similar problem, but it starts to reappear this week for IDE + Open command in Selblocks / forXML cycle. Searching solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably in the time of the question it touches this problem:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5165

and there is an workaround:

```
 Command = storeEval
 Target = window.location.hash='events/5000/participants/7011'
```

This would be no solution for current problems with timeout, as Selenium-IDE is already in 2.xx version.